# Notepad++ highlights curly braces in red

Tags: notepad++

I do not know how to explain about uploading photos.
Notepad++ highlights the curly braces in red while and the Visual Studio Code does not. 
[image: side by side comprison]

Answer (score 6):

This is not an indication of an error - Notepad++ just highlights matching brackets. This happens if you place the caret (blinking line which indicates where you're entering text) next to a bracket.

This is a very common behaviour for code editors: you can see the same behaviour in Visual Studio Code on the left, however instead of colouring the brackets themselves, the editor changes the background of just those two brackets.

With the default colour scheme Notepad++ uses, the highlight is red. If you wish, you can adjust that by going to Settings -> Style Configurator -> make sure **Global** is selected in the Language list -> go to **Brace highlight style** in the Style list.

[image: Style Configurator]

Alternatively, you can choose a different theme from the dropdown menu at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I probably did not explain correctly. My idea is that the notepad++ is done very well by seeing the code in the curly quotes, and when it is visual studio, it is not or is not set as a notepad++. With a visual studio, it highlights the part that is outside the curly braces with the white line, and it is more practical for me to be a notepad++ when there is more to see where it can be seen in a legible opening and closing curly bracket.

Comment: I assume Visual Studio Code has a way of changing the colour settings similar to Notepad++ but I don't use there are options to change that behaviour.